# The rules to 2 pair poker hands?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules

I had a 7 and 2 in my hand
My opponent had  a 9 and a J
The floor was 4 4 7 9 2
Who wins?

Answer (score 2):

Your best 5 card hand is 7 7 4 4 9
Opponent has a better hand: 9 9 4 4 J

9's and 4's beats 7's and 4's

The best possible 5 card combination utilizing your hole cards and the board is what determines the strength of the hand.